# Why my bootstrapdoensn't effect on Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

Hello I have a project on Angular.

I install bootstrap, and I added to angular.json but still didn't effect, So I restart app but still same, here is my code;

[image: angular.json]
[image: this is my component]
[image: bootstrap folder]

How can I fix this? Thank you.

I try restart my application,
I update my packages,
I check bootstarp path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that :
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
**with ../**

Comment: I tried but it's still same

Comment: after change restart the project npm start; if not you can go to the style.css and add that : @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

Comment: I did this to but still same idk why it's happening

Comment: add that in style.css : @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; as a temporary solution